# TLP tpacpi-bet (acpi_call) = inactive (kernel error)

Tags: battery, thinkpad, 21.10, tlp

Trying to use TLP to recalibrate the batteries on my thinkpad T470s.  I am following the instructions [here](https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/ubuntu.html#)  I am running Ubuntu 21.10, I have disabled secure boot in both the bios and using `sudo mokutil --disable-verification` as I have seen that this could be causing the issue.  Any thoughts on how I can get this working?  I am decent with linux, but still have a lot to learn lol.

Answer (score 0):

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=989384 resp. https://gist.github.com/roadkell/9e98db6656e28fbbf1bf51082040f67f.

I just compiled version 1.2.2 from https://github.com/nix-community/acpi_call/releases/tag/v1.2.2 and simply replaced acpi_call.ko with the compiled one and did a reboot.